# Is it inadvisable to instantiate data to process it?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, design-patterns

Been running in circles on this so I thought I’d put it out there. I’m new to programming and have been learning JavaScript.

I’m trying to apply the Object Oriented perspective to my design, which involves a large collection of dynamically created objects. These objects need to be stored in a database, and accessed regularly. It feels weird to get a bunch (say 20) of items from the database and immediately pass them into a constructor to gain access to their functionality, does it feel weird because it’s a strange thing to be doing? Basically each object needs to be its own instance because it’s properties are unique, but it is of a “class” which serves a similar purpose.

I’m not sure if that made any sense, if not, I apologize. Basically.. is it weird to be instantiating a ton of data you get from a database? Should my class be broader? Will delete if this question sucks.

P.S. I know this may sound wooey but one of the hard things to get a handle on when you don’t know what you’re doing is the stuff which seems assumed to those accustomed. Even a “it depends” answer would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use object-oriented programming, which usually means associating behavior and data in the same container (an object), then it's not odd that when you retrieve the data from data-only storage like a database or file you have to do something to connect that data to the behaviors you want to associate with it. In fact, there's a whole industry for it: [Object/Relational Mapping tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It's not at all "wierd." :-)

*How* you do that is largely up to you and mostly a matter of plumbing, and that's where various ORM tools come in (or you roll your own ORM layer). You could pass 20 data items to a constructor, but that's...one heck of a parameter list. :-)

Instead, it's fairly typical to have a helper class or function that knows how to get data from the DB and knows how to build instances of your class; that way, your class doesn't have to know about the DB. The helper class or function queries the DB and creates the class instances. (ORM tools can help you build those largely automatically.)

On a plumbing level, there are several ways for that function to apply the DB data to the class instance:

1. It could just assign the properties directly:

   ```js
   /* ...get the data... */
   const ex = new Example();
   ex.prop1 = data1;
   ex.prop2 = data2;
   ex.prop3 = data3;
   // ...
   ```

   That assumes they're all meant to be properties and not just private information used by the instance.
2. It could pass the constructor a [*data transfer object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTO), and then the constructor could use the named properties on the DTO to initialize the instance as appropriate. With 20 data items, this is a popular choice.
3. #2 can get a bit verbose and hard to maintain (you have to write assignments in at least two places, the DB code creating the DTO and then the constructor code copying the properties from it). So you could throw some meta-programming at it. You *could* just assume that all the properties on the DTO are valid for the object and use `Object.assign`:

   ```js
   class Example {
       constructor(dto) {
           Object.assign(this, dto);
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

   ...but that means if the DTO has properties on it that aren't relevant to `Example` instances, they'll get those properties. Often that's fine because you're in full control of the DTO, but if you want to be more explicit, you could have a list of properties:

   ```js
   class Example {
       static PROPS = ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", /*...*/];
       constructor(dto) {
           for (const name of Example.PROPS) {
               this[name] = dto[name];
           }
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. You can use a mix of approaches if some of the properties on the DTO are meant to end up as properties on the instance, and other ones aren't. Looking at #3's code, for instance, `PROPS` might only list the 10 (say) that should end up as props and then other code in the constructor could use the other 10 (say) that were used in another way.

There are lots and lots of ways to the plumbing, but the fundamental answer to "is it weird to connect data to behaviors when getting data from the DB and using object-oriented programming" is "no, it isn't weird at all."